# Eigen L How can I compute the inner product of a row vector from a sparse matrix and a dense vector? What is the efficiency?

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

SparseMatrix SM;
MatrixXd f;

SM is a m*n sparse Matrix(0.18%), and f is a n*1 column vector.
I want to get the ith row vector of SM and product it with f. How should I write the code?

I was also worried about the efficiency. As many redundant zeros may be involved in computation.

Answer (score 0):

If SM is a column major matrix, then indexing one its row is very inefficient and essentially a no-go if performance matter. If SM is row-major, then you can simply do `SM.row(i).dot(f)`, and the cost will be in the order of the number of non zeros in `SM.row(i)`.

Comment: We don't even know what language this is. There's probably more than one language with a class called `SparseMatrix` which is used for sparse matrices.

Comment: The flag `eigen` is supposed to refer to the C++ Eigen library.